# Monitoring best experimental setup in EXCEL with structure

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am conducting a batch of experiments, and keep track of the following quantities in a table:

- Subject of the experiment
- Day of the experiment
- Context of the experiment
- Expected result for that day
- Actual result for that day
- Relative error for that day

These quantities are in a table whose columns are labelled SUBJECT, DAY, CONTEXT, EXPECTED, ACTUAL, RELATIVE. I want to produce a table monitoring the experiments, results, where for all SUBJECT * DAY combinations, the CONTEXT leading to least relative ERROR is displayed, as well as corresponding EXPECTED, ACTUAL and RELATIVE.

It seems that a combination of INDEX, VLOOKUP, MATCH and MIN could be used to achieve this, however I could not manage to do it right using *structured references,* which is important to me since the structure of the tables evolves a lot.

As an example data

```
| SUBJECT | DAY | CONTEXT | EXPECTED | ACTUAL | RELATIVE |
| A       | 1   |       x |       42 |     0  |     100% |
| A       | 1   |       y |       42 |    42  |       0% |
| B       | 1   |       x |       21 |    10  |      50% |
| B       | 1   |       x |       21 |     0  |     100% |
| A       | 2   |       x |        3 |     1  |      66% |
```

I should have the following in my monitoring table:

```
| A       | 1   |       y |       42 |    42  |       0% |
| B       | 1   |       x |       21 |    10  |      50% |
```

As a side-note, I actually have several measures in the data table, and want to monitor each of them separately.

EDIT. As suggested in comments, I tried to build a pivot table. I was able to produce a pivot table with lines labelled by SUBJECT and columns labelled by DAYS where the best RELATIVE error is displayed. This is still very far from the monitoring table above.

Comment: Have you tried a Pivot Table?

Comment: I have not but I am not familiar to this concept.  How can get some acquaintance to it?

Comment: try this: http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/

Comment: @AndiMohr Thank you it looks promising!  Am I very wrong if I think to Pivot Tables as adding some SQL-ish features to Plain Tables?

Comment: Pivot tables do not modify or add anything to the original data.They can be very powerful tools once learned. As the page you were referred to puts it "Excel pivot tables are very useful and powerful feature of MS Excel. They can be used to summarize, analyze, explore and present your data."

Comment: As Charlie says, Pivot Tables aren't really there to mimic SQL functionality. If that's what you're looking for, read up on Powerpivot: http://chandoo.org/wp/2013/01/21/introduction-to-power-pivot/

Comment: If number is huge, why not set up a DB for it in something like MS Access.....SQL queries are a very powerful way to organize, access and filter data..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this in excel it wouldn't be that difficult but using some helper columns would be beneficial.

I would add a unique row identifier and also potentially another column with concatenates your subject and day `=B3 & C3`.  Which would make creating your unique values easier in excel.

In your results table you would first find your the experiment ID you want and then fill in the columns using either `vlookup` or `index`+`match`.

The formula for the experiment ID is an array formula entered using ctrl+shift+enter and finds the minimum value in relative column that matches both subject and day.  If there are two with the same value it will pick the same one

Formula is (enter with ctrl+shift+enter) in cell A10:
       `=INDEX($A$3:$A$7,MATCH(MIN(IF($B$3:$B$7=B10,IF($C$3:$C$7=C10,$G$3:$G$7,9999),9999)),IF($B$3:$B$7=B10,IF($C$3:$C$7=C10,$G$3:$G$7,9999),9999),0))`

For the other columns just use a lookup (or I prefer index match)

Cell D10 formula is `=INDEX(D$3:D$7,MATCH($A10,$A$3:$A$7,0))`.  This formula can be copied into all the other cells and will work as well.

Gordon
[image]